# Encrypt and sign with specific secret key

Tags: gpg

I have an OpenPGP smart card key (YubiKey NEO) as well as a local secret key installed in my GnuPG keyring.

I'd like to encrypt and sign a file with my card's key, not the key in my keyring. How can I specify what key I'd like to sign with?

If my filesystem secret key id is `DEADBEEF` and my smartcard key is `DEADBEE5`, how do I sign with that key?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should specify `--default-key`:

```
gpg -s --default-key DEADBEE5 input > output
```

and check afterwards with

```
gpg -d < output | head -1
```

From the `gpg man` page( `--sign` section):

> The key to be used for signing  is
>                 chosen  by  default  or  can  be  set  with the --local-user and
>                 --default-key options.

Comment: `gpg: conflicting commands` when I try to encrypt and sign.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Sorry --sign-key is for signing other keys with a specific key. I updated the answer (and tested beforehand this time).

Comment: `--default-*` makes little sense on the command line. These options are for the config file.

Comment: The difference between `--local-user` and `--default-key` is that `--local-user` will give an error if you specify a non-existent key. With `--default-key`, it will ignore a non-existent key and use the first key in the keyring.

Answer (score 36):

The signing key is selected with `-u` / `--local-user`:

```
gpg --local-user 0xDEADBEE5 --sign file
```

This option can be given several times in order to combine signatures of several keys:

```
gpg --local-user 0xDEADBEE5 --local-user 0x12345678 --sign file
```

Comment: According to the man page using `--local-user` is the same as using `--default-user` as in my answer

Comment: @Anthon It leads to the same result. That doesn't mean that `--default-*` should be recommended for this usage. I have been on the GnuPG mailinglist for years. I have never seen something like that before.

Comment: Well yeah, it looks like the issue came up once on gnupg-users and that you where the one who provided the answer with **your** reading of the man page ;-). For me specifying an option with `-key` in its name feels much more appropriate when I want to use a specific key than specifying something with `-user` YMMV.

Comment: I think @Anthon meant `--default-key` in his comment above. Running with that, one difference between `--local-user` and `--default-key` in my experience, is that the first fails if a matching key isn't present, while the second will fall back to other keys. For that reason, I'd be very wary of putting `--default-key` in scripts.

Comment: I tested and confirmed @JackO'Connor's comment with gpg 2.2.4. The man for `--default-key` says `If there is no secret key available for any of the specified values, GnuPG  will not emit an error message but continue as if this option wasn't given.`

Comment: `--local-user` can also use the email. Oh Yeah!